# Как сделать накладывающиеся границы в CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать накладывающиеся границы в CSS?
[Сайт пример](http://www.furfur.me/) ( окно навигации ).
Нужно, чтобы `border` был на всех элементах по 2px, но так как элементы расположены вплотную друг к другу, получается, что между ними 4px:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px 100px;
  background-color: #262626;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.div1,
.div3 {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #44B3E2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5EE244;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.div1:hover,
.div2:hover,
.div3:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #3e3e3e;
}

.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  border-right: 2px solid #3e3e3e;
}

.div1:before,
.div2:before,
.div3:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.div1:hover:before,
.div2:hover:before,
.div3:hover:before {
  border: 2px solid #e6c87c;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="div1">блок 1</div>
  <div class="div2">блок 1</div>
  <div class="div3">блок 1</div>
</nav>
```

---

**UPD** - пояснение:

Проблема в том, что Вы делаете видимые границы каждому элементу со всех сторон.

Что делает код выше:

1. Для родителя `nav` ставится граница в 2px.
2. Чтобы не создавать лишние границы ставятся только границы справа, только блокам `.div1` и `.div2`.
3. Для детей (`.div1`, `.div2`, `.div3`) создается псевдоэлемент [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::before) с размерами -2px с каждой стороны и невидимой границей в 2px, которая становится видимой (устанавливается цвет) [при наведении](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover), т.е.:

   ```
   .div1:hover:before,
   .div2:hover:before,
   .div3:hover:before {
     border: 2px solid #e6c87c;
   }
   ```

Comment: Объясните, в чем проблема.

Comment: @VerNick какая проблема?

Comment: Всмысле что нужно добавить для получения правильного результата. Объясните.

Comment: @VerNick добавлено описание. но по коду и так было понятно.

Comment: Новичку(и не только) было бы непонятно. Вот за такой ответ я поставлю плюс.

Comment: @VerNick хорошо, теперь просьба более понятна

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так:
для родителя -  border-collapse: collapse;
для элементов - display: table-cell;